# Django ManyToMany unique

Tags: python, django, orm

I want to create model `Team` for a team of variable number of players. What comes to mind is something like:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    players = models.ManyToManyField(
        Player,
    )
```

The problem here is that I don't want duplicates: different `Team` instances with the same set of players should not exist, but Django does not allow `unique` on `ManyToMany`. How can I work around that?

Comment: Even if the m2m is "unique", then this would still make it possible that a team has `[a, b]` as players whereas another has `[a, c]` as players, so you probably do not want that either?

Comment: It looks like you want a one-to-many relation, so adding a `ForeignKey` from `Player` to `Team`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, that would be fine, actually. I just don't want [a, b] and [a, b] to be different teams.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, huh, now that I gave it more thought, I understand that you might be right: I cannot allow one player in two teams for one event, so I might go away with creating some `PlayerEvent` relation, with foreign key to a `Team`. Thank you!